# NoClassDefFoundError when using OrmLite

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, ormlite

Below is my `DBConfig.java` class definition:

```
public class DBConfig extends OrmLiteConfigUtil {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBConfig2.class.getName());
    private static final String CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "ormlite_config.txt";

    private static final Class<?>[] CLASSES = new Class[]{
            User.class
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        File rawFolder = new File("res/raw");

        if (!rawFolder.exists()) {
            boolean rawCreated = rawFolder.mkdirs();

            if (!rawCreated) {
                logger.warning("could not create raw folder");
                System.exit(1);
            } else {
                logger.info("created raw folder");
            }
        }

        writeConfigFile(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, CLASSES);
    }
}
```

And my `User.java` class:

```
    @DatabaseTable(tableName = "users")
public class User {
    private static final String ID = "user_id";
    private static final String USER_NAME = "name";
    private static final String USER_AGE = "age";
    private static final String USER_DOB = "dob";

    @DatabaseField(columnName = ID, id = true)
    private long id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = USER_NAME)
    private String name;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = USER_AGE)
    private int age;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = USER_DOB)
    private String dob;

    // getters and setters...

}
```

When I run DBConfig using the run configuration captured below, I get the error message `Error: Could not find or load main class com.alex.bestapp.DBConfig
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/OrmLiteConfigUtil`.

[image]

I have however correctly added the needed dependencies in the module's build.gradle file:
`implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.0'
implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'`

Any help on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your classpath.  I don't know how to help you fix it however since I don't know or recognize the IDE you are using.

Comment: @Gray I'm using Android Studio 3.0

Comment: Yeah sorry.  I don't have any experience with it.